# How do I upload video but not have https://

Tags: youtube

I am trying to put a video in a game.  It requires a link, but the link cannot have HTTPS://  as the start.  It needs the HTTP://

Is there a service that does this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the payload may be video but this is primarily about network communication in a mobile app

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you just use http:// instead of https:// in front of any youtube video it should work the same.

Comment: It does in a browser, however I'm pretty sure Youtube redirects links like that to https, so it might not work with whatever game/app he's building ...

Comment: On youtube help for embedding https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters they use plain http://